# xslt - any restriction with the length of Metadata name?

Tags: xslt

I am new to this forum. I need to parse/read an xml which cotains lots of metadata(as below). I have two read a specific meta value based on the bu value, for example if my bu value is '987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc' I have to get the value "d581452fa9ba3110VgnVCM10000038ccc5abRCRD|def". My question, is there any restriction with metadata name length? for some reason my xslt logic is not reading this value(select="MT[@N=$partialval]/@V").

**XSLT snippet:**

```
   <xsl:for-each select='./MT[@N="bu"]'>
  <xsl:variable name="temp_bu" select="./@V"/>
  <xsl:variable name="partialval" select="'987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc'"/>
  <xsl:if test="contains($partialval, $temp_bu)">
    <xsl:variable name="partialbuval" select="MT[@N=$partialval]/@V"/>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="concat('file://',$partialbuval,'test',$partialval)"/>
  </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**Sample xml structure:**

```
    <MT N="bu" V="12345678910111121314sdnfske34234123234abc"/>
    <MT N="12345678910111121314sdnfske34234123234abc" V="02715148a3e7a110VgnVCM1000001b89c5abRCRD|abc"/>
    <MT N="12345678910111121314sdnfske34234123234abc_name" V="Item one"/>
    <MT N="bu" V="987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc"/>
    <MT N="987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc" V="d581452fa9ba3110VgnVCM10000038ccc5abRCRD|def"/>
    <MT N="987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc_name" V="Item two"/>
    <MT N="bu" V="qqqqqwwwweeeee1112223333ssdfff3334sssssabc"/>
    <MT N="qqqqqwwwweeeee1112223333ssdfff3334sssssabc" V="d581452fa9ba3110VgnVCM10000038ccc5abRCRD|ghi"/>
    <MT N="qqqqqwwwweeeee1112223333ssdfff3334sssssabc_name" V="Item three"/>
    <MT N="bu" V="hhhheeeertisodfnsdifwoein12345sfjsoif234defgh"/>
    <MT N="hhhheeeertisodfnsdifwoein12345sfjsoif234defgh" V="d581452fa9ba3110VgnVCM10000038ccc5abRCRD|jkl"/>
    <MT N="hhhheeeertisodfnsdifwoein12345sfjsoif234defgh_name" V="Item four"/>
```

Seeing the **output** as (partialbuval value is missing in this string)
"file://test987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc"

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here. Appreciate if you could help me.

Thanks,
Amarnath

Comment: For some reason, below xml snippet and the sample xml got removed from my question.  
**XSLT snippet:** 

<xsl:for-each select='./MT[@N="bu"]'>
 <xsl:variable name="temp_bu" select="./@V"/>
 <xsl:variable name="partialval" select="'987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc'"/>
 <xsl:if test="contains($partialval, $temp_bu)">
  <xsl:variable name="partialbuval" select="MT[@N=$partialval]/@V"/>
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="concat('file://',$partialbuval,'test',$partialval)"/>
 </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each>

Comment: Please edit your question and **do not post code in comments**. See how: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: **Sample xml structure:**

<MT N="bu" V="12345678910111121314sdnfske34234123234abc"/>
<MT N="12345678910111121314sdnfske34234123234abc" V="02715148a3e7a110VgnVCM1000001b89c5abRCRD|abc"/>
<MT N="12345678910111121314sdnfske34234123234abc_name" V="Item one"/>
<MT N="bu" V="987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc"/>
<MT N="987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc" V="d581452fa9ba3110VgnVCM10000038ccc5abRCRD|def"/>
<MT N="987654321abcdefghijklmnopaslasjdoiwneois123abc_name" V="Item two"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your requirement.  But in the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./MT[@N="bu"]">
   <xsl:variable ... select="MT[@N=$partialval]/@V"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

the second `select` will never select anything.  That is because `xsl:for-each` changes the context.  So within the body of the `xsl:for-each` (also called its *sequence constructor*) the *context item* is the current `MT` element being *looked at* in this current iteration of the `xsl:for-each`.

So the second select expression asks for *any `MT` element, direct child of the current `MT` element*, and there is not any.

Extra tip: `./` at the beginning of an XPath expression is always meaningless.  The only situation where starting an expression with a dot is `.//`.  So `./MT` is always equivalent to `MT`, which is also more readable.